# How to type bold parentheses in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, ieeetran

How can I write bold/very bold parentheses?

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}   
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
\left( something \right)
\end{document}
```

However, I want the     `\left(`    and  `\right)`   to appear bold.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
\left( something  \right)
\end{dmath}

\begin{dmath}
\boldsymbol{\left(\right.} something \boldsymbol{\left.\right)}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used your solution above but it gave me small parentheses which unlike \left( did not grow up adaptively in size

Comment: @Elnaz I am afraid that is a limitation of this approach. If you use a for example a big smbol like `\sum` you can use  simply `\boldsymbol{\Biggl(}\sum \boldsymbol{\Biggl)}` ( or  `\big`, `\Big` or `\bigg`).

Comment: You can define something like 
    \newcommand{\bbracket}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\left(\vphantom{#1}\right.}{#1}\boldsymbol{\left.\vphantom{#1}\right)}}
so that the heights of the brackets can adjust with the expression inside your brackets.