# Bold \Big parenthesis in math mode

Tags: delimiters, boldmath, bm, boldsymbol

Is there a way to print a **bold `\Big` parenthesis** in math mode? If yes, is there also a way to print a bold parenthesis of any size (up to `\Bigg` for instance).

I've tried the following approach but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

$\bm{\Big (} \Big ($

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to type bold parentheses in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240288/how-to-type-bold-parentheses-in-math-mode)

Comment: @jGaboardi it is although the question title in the referenced post doesn't mention large delimiters (and the answer there does not work for large delimiters and is somewhat sub-optimal for normal delimiters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27058

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
 \SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

$\bm{\Big (} \Big ($

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Indeed, the bold version *is* bold, but it's not the same shape as the nonbold version.  If only bold parentheses are needed, that whouldn't be noticeable, but there might be a visual clash if both weights are needed.